# Remove chapter number only in selected chapters with titlesec

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I am using a report template for a thesis. This template names every chapter with "Chapter X" followed by the title of the chapter. I would like to change it for the introduction and the conclusions, without removing them from the table of content, with the chapters in between being numbered from 1 to N. If I use

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{3pt}{\Huge}
```

I remove the header as I wish, but there is no way to limit this change only to intro and conclusions, and all the chapters are affected.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `\chapter*{Introduction}` makes an unnumbered chapter

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler if you switch to `book`, with a simple redefinition of `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` that just remove the `\pagenumbering` commands in them.

**Note 1.** The `openany` option is used here just not to get blank pages in the picture.

**Note 2.** `titlesec` is irrelevant for the solution. Add it to your liking.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

% continuous numbering
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
}
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}

\backmatter

\chapter{Conclusions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you can't change the class from `report`, use `\chapter*` with a suitable `\addcontentsline` instruction.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\chapter{First}

\chapter*{Conclusions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\end{document}
```